# Name Error Django

Tags: django

I get a Name error while trying to run my project,

urls.py

```
import os
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
#from bookmarks.views import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from preview.views import *
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    (r'^catalog/$', home),
)
```

views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html")
```

index.html

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "C:/python27/Djangoprojects/ecomstore/preview",
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

Error

```
NameError at /catalog/
name 'home' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'home' is not defined
Exception Location: C:\Python27\Djangoprojects\ecomstore\..\ecomstore\urls.py in <module>, line 12
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
```

Comment: traceback maybe? I don't believe it happened until there is a traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `home` in your `preview/views.py` file?  Somehow your `from preview.views import *` did not import it in.

In which case, can you try to do

```
urlpatterns = patterns('preview.views',

    (r'^catalog/$', 'home'),
)
```

instead?

And double check that the `preview` app is included in your `INSTALLED_APPS` tuple in your `settings.py` file.

Comment: preview app is added as well

Comment: Can you try directly referencing `preview.views.home` using the above syntax instead?

Comment: (r'^catalog/$', 'preview.views.home'),--this one worked..thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a very straight forward error. 'home' is not defined.

You haven't imported it.

Think of what happens when you open a python terminal and type in

```
> foobar
> # NameError
```

Either import it in your urls.py or use string notation `'myapp.views.myfunc'`

Comment: I assume by `name` you mean `home`.

Comment: @user1050619, apparently not. Because you wouldn't get the error otherwise.